# Laravel 4 - redirect from a repository when not returning the called method

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-4, controller

I am using a repository pattern in my Laravel 4 project but come across something which I think I am doing incorrectly.

I am doing user validation, before saving a new user.

I have one method in my controller for this:

```
public function addNewUser() {
    $validation = $this->userCreator->validateUser($input);

    if ( $validation['success'] === false )
    {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validation['errors'])
            ->withInput($input);
    }

    return $this->userCreator->saveUser($input);
}
```

Then the validateUser method is:

```
public function validate($input) {
    $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email_address' => 'unique:users'
    );

    $messages = [
    ];

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        $failed = $validation->messages();
        $response = ['success' => false, 'errors' => $failed];
        return $response;
    }

    $response = ['success' => true];
    return $response;
}
```

This may be okay, but I dont like doing the if statement in my controller? I would rather be able to handle that in my validation class.

But to be able to redirect from the validation class, I need to return the method in the controller.

What if I then want to have 5  methods called, I cant return them all?

I would like to be able to simply call the methods in order, then in their respective class handle what I need to and if there is any errors redirect or deal with them. But if everything is okay, simply ignore it and move to the next function.

So example:

```
public function addNewUser()
{
  $this->userCreator->validateUser($input);
  $this->userCreator->formatInput($input);
  $this->userCreator->sendEmails($input);
  return $this->userCreator->saveUser($input);
}
```

If doing the if statement in the controller isn't as bad as I think then I can continue, but this seems incorrect?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using if thens in a controller and I do it all the time as the controller is where you store your application logic.  I would probably put all the validateUser, formatInput, and saveUser functions into a single function in the User Controller called store.  I would however have a separate class for the sendEmails that you call from the store function.

Comment: @Joshua The controller should not be where your application logic is stored, it should be in services.

Comment: @Joshua, the controller does not need to know the actual logic, it is just a transporter.

Answer (score 0):

For repository pattern, you can use this :-

setup your basemodel like this

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model{

   protected static $rules=null;
   protected $errors=null;


   public function validateForCreation($data)
   {
       $validation=\Validator::make($data,static::$rules);
       if($validation->fails())
       {
           $this->errors=$validation->messages();
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   /**
    * @return errors
    */
   public function getErrors() { return $this->errors; }
}
```

now in your repository, add these methods

```
protected $model;

protected $errors=null;

public function model(){ return $this->model; }

public function getErrors(){ return $this->errors; }

public function create($inputs)
{
    if(!$this->model->validateForCreation($inputs))
    {
        $this->errors=$this->model->getErrors();
        return false;
    }
    $new=$this->model->create($inputs);

    return $new;
}
```

and the controller will look like this..

```
public function postCreate(Request $request)
{
    $inputs=$request->all();

    if($new=$this->repo->create($inputs))
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('flash_message','Created Successfully');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->repo->getErrors())
        ->with('flash_message','Whoops! there is some problem with your input.');
}
```